# Calculating ratio between 2 different area polygons in each cell of a given polygon grid using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm trying to calculate the ratio of the areas of 2 polygons (Sealed Surfaces and unsealed Surfaces) in each cell of a given polygon (fishnet) grid. The areas are in one featureclass and I also appended the grids to this featureclass. What I want is to have a value (ratio) for each grid cell of the fishnet polygon.

I can imagine that this is possible with the field calculator and some scripting, but I never used Python and therefore I'm having no clue at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Summarize Within Tool would do what I want. I did what you described but the output is not exactly what I need. Somehow, the Summarized Area (the area of the sealed surfaces) of for example an fully unsealed surface is bigger than the area of one single grid. However, the Sum shape_area (of the calculated group field) has the correct area.
So at the end I have the result I wanted, but I don't really know why and if I understood the tool right.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool for that! It's called [Summarize Within](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/summarize-within.htm)

**How I would fill out your parameters in the tool:**

Summarized Layer: Your surfaces feature class

Polygon or Bin: Polygon

Summary Polygons: Fishnet feature class

Check Add Shape Summary

Shape Units: Whatever you'd like, but if you can, choose whatever the area unit for your projection is

Standard Summary Fields: Shape_Area

Group By Field: The field in your surfaces feature class that you use to differentiate between Sealed and Unsealed

Choose good location for your Group By Summary Table. You will use this to join to your output!

**Important!!**

You must join your Group By Summary Table (.csv) to your Summarize Within output using the JOIN_ID field. You can then add a field to hold your ratio of surface:fishnet polygon. Field Calculate this field with the equation of  (sum_area field in the joined table/area of 1 fishnet cell). Make sure they are in the same units! **If not, you will have to either use the proper scale factor in your field calculator or create another field to hold the area with the proper units.**